# Как оптимизировать CodeIgniter + POST?

Tags: post, php, оптимизация

Вот такой кот точно требует оптимизации. CodeIgniter 1/7/2

```
$i1['category'] = $this->input->post('category');
$i1['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
$i1['fncmat'] = $this->input->post('fncmat');
$i1['fnccat'] = $this->input->post('fnccat');
$i1['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
$i1['twitter'] = $this->input->post('twitter');
$i1['rss'] = $this->input->post('rss');
$i1['sitemap'] = $this->input->post('sitemap');
$i1['control_image'] = $this->input->post('control_image');
$i1['control_comments_list'] = $this->input->post('control_comments_list');
$i1['control_twitter'] = $this->input->post('control_twitter');
$i1['control_public'] = $this->input->post('control_public');
$i1['control_aggregators'] = $this->input->post('control_aggregators');
$i1['control_notify'] = $this->input->post('control_notify');
$i1['control_comments_allow'] = $this->input->post('control_comments_allow');
$i1['control_mailer'] = $this->input->post('control_mailer');
```

Массив $i1 будет обновлять поля в базе данных

Comment: Выглядит примерно как - вот вам конюшня, гребитесь... <br> А если серьезно - приведенный код особо не соптимизируешь, или вы имеете введу оптимизацию самого запроса?

Answer (score 2):

Что вам мешает получить все данные пост-запроса

```
$post_recv = $this->input->post(); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
```

Я думаю, посмотреть, что в данном методе возвращается не составит труда?

А затем, подозреваю, что можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией для цикла:

```
foreach($post_reqv as $key => $value)...
```

Comment: Лично мне вообще непонятен вопрос...

Comment: А вот Dex понятно, и он правильно ответил на вопрос. Проверить что возвращается нужно с помощью var_dump($post_recv) и сразу все пакетом в массив для базы отправить. А вы AlexWindHope видимо новичек еще тот.

Comment: boolean false. Дело в том что возврат массива сделали в 2.0.2 версии, а я на старой 1.7.2

Comment: @Increazon

![][1]
[1]: http://img.playground.ru/images/7/8/okay-face.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз у тебя поля input соответсвуют, то самый простой способ:

```
$global_post = $this->input->post();
$id = 1;
foreach ($global_post as $key => $value)
    $this->db->update('table', array($key => $value), 'id = '.$id);
```

Comment: сударь, ваш код отвратителен, если я правильно понимаю что он делает.

1. пришло 5 полей - делаем 5 апдейтов, че нам жалко чтоли.

2. пришло поле id, обновляем его без вопросов! мы же доверяем пользователю.

на мой взгляд лучше сделать вот так: 


 $global_post = $this->input->post();
 $id = 1;

 $fields = array('name', 'time', 'date', 'product', 'profile',  'filial', 'article');
 $values = array();

 foreach ($global_post as $key => $value)
  if(in_array($key, $fields)
   $values[$key] => $value;

 $this->db->update('table', $values, 'id = '.$id);

Comment: можно было в моём варианте добавить исключающее условие на поле id, или на те поля которые надо, но ваш вариант лучше, согласен, доработан!
спасибо за критику!)